# Google-appengine-standard - routing via vpc_access_connector

Tags: google-app-engine

We're trying to get our GAE standard app connected through one of our VPC's which is being used to connect to our VPN clients. VPC (rsvpn) runs openvpn as a client, connecting to our OpenVPN subnet. It is configured with ip_forward and is setup to forward all inbound packets destined for 172.16.0.0/24 through tun0. VPC networks global routing is configured to route 172.16.0.0/24 via rsvpn.
When I hop on another VPC, I'm able to ping out to the VPN subnet as expected.
However, the GAE app's packets destined for 172.16.0.0/24 are not being routed via rsvpn.

We did some digging and found that we probably need to deploy the app via gcloud beta, making use of the vpc_access_connector, so we did this as well. vpc_access_connector configured with subnet 10.8.0.0/28 and the app was configured with the appropriate config. Re-deploy the app, and it still doesn't hit the rsvpn server.

When we look at the running config for the app, we see no mention of the vpc_access_connector, but it's clearly configured in the app.yaml.

Discussed with google support. They confirm that our setup should be correct and that the app should be making use of our vpc routing tables. They're looking into it currently.

I'm wondering though if anyone might be able to shed some light on this. Google's documentation isn't amazing, and I find pretty consistently that it's just often wrong. I've heard a few references that sorta might suggest that the vpc_access_connector may only work in flex environments, but then the docs, and google support say it should work in standard.

Anyone every made this setup work?

Comment: The response on the issue will be provided on the case that you have open with Google support. If you feel that there is something useful in the answer to share with the community, feel free to add it here.

Comment: When deploying with vpc_access_connector are you using `gcloud beta deploy` or normal `gcloud deploy`. Since its a beta feature, it needs the beta flag else the parameter is ignored

Answer (score 1):

Our solution ended up being adding Compute Network User permissions to the profile executing the deployment. Unfortunately this permissions error isn't logged out to us but rather internal to Google. This appeared to solve all issues we were experiencing in the Standard Environment. Also make sure to use `gcloud beta app deploy`

Comment: Hi, I'm having the same problem and it so far it seems adding the permission really helped.